# Is there a way to check what programming languages and libraries are installed on a Mac?

Tags: python

Sorry if it's a silly question-- roughly new to programming. Over the last year I've installed Python + a lot of libraries on my computer and I'm trying to remove what I don't need.

Comment: Depends on what you installed and how. If using a package manager like Homebrew/pip/etc., the package manager can usually tell you what you installed though it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `pip` you can use this command to list all installed libraries:

```
pip list
```

Note that this is in your terminal, not ran in python.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a code for getting the list of modules and libraries installed in the python environment:

```
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)
```